# Ruby installation results in Terminal opening as cat

Tags: ruby, bash, terminal, rvm, cat

I tried to install Ruby on my computer. I used [About.com guide](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyversionmanager/ss/Installing-Ruby-On-Snow-Leopard-With-Rvm.htm).   The terminal opens with the label `cat` at the top (after briefly flashing `login`, `find`, and `bash`), and it won't run anything I type. I think this is the result of step 6 of the guide, which told me to enter:

```
$ cat >>~/.bash_profile
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

How can I change the default shell to bash? I tried going to Preferences and changing "Shells open with" to Command `/bin/bash`, but no luck. I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to get to bash. I updated to OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Why would you use an About.com guide to install RVM? The [RVM site](http://rvm.io) has the definitive information about [installing it](http://rvm.io/rvm/install); Every other site is secondary information at best, so go to the source. And, READ EVERYTHING on the install page before you start. RVM is powerful and flexible and people screw it up all the time because they didn't take the time to follow the directions.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend just opening a text editor and pasting `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` into your `.bash_profile`.  You can do this in Terminal by doing `open ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Awesome!  To close this question, please click the green checkbox next to this answer. :)